# Using Bibliographies - where do I place the .bib-file

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am working on my FIRST `.tex` document. I have my `.bib` exported from Zotero. Where do I need to place my `.bib` file so as to enable TeXShop to find it? Do I need to specify a path like I do when including figures? 
I would like to cite by author/year and have a list of references at the bottom. I am clearly making a mistake at the beginning or at the end, I am following directions in chapter 12 of Kopka & Daly Guide to LaTeX 2004, and I am missing something.

This is the error message I get when I run BibTeX:

```
 This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2011) The top-level auxiliary
 file: 06_19_Etapa_1-1.aux The style file: alpha.bst I couldn't open
 database file MyLibrary.bib
 ---line 37 of file 06_19_Etapa_1-1.aux  : \bibdata{MyLibrary  :                   }

I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file 06_19_Etapa_1-1.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "hess_strobophotoglottographic_2000"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does your `.tex` document have a line like `\bibliography{MyLibrary}`?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to have the .bib file in the same folder as the .tex file you're working with. Or you can specify a path to it.